# Shape of dynamic_rnn

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I implemented a stacked LSTM network in TensorFlow, using:

```
# Stack up multiple LSTM layers
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_layer() for _ in range(lstm_layers)])
```

where `lstm_layer()` is defined as:

```
def lstm_layer():
    return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size, state_is_tuple=True)
```

I use a batch size of 20 and a sequence length of 200. The 200 is a maximum, the rest is padded with zeros. I use a dynamic_rnn where I pass the sequence length for each sample:

```
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, 
                                     embed,
                                     sequence_length=seq_lengths,
                                     initial_state=initial_state)
```

when I look at the last output using `outputs[:,-1,:]`, the `h` vector has shape `(2, batch_size, cell.output_size)`, where `cell.output_size` is simply the number of units in the top LSTM layer (128 in my case, equal to `lstm_size`).

Where does the 2 come from? In my understanding, I should simply have 128 outputs for each sample in the batch, not 2 times that number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somehow the previously posted answer was deleted, don't know why.

Comment: Is `lstm_layers` equal to 2?

Comment: It's equal to 1. The problem was already solved in the (deleted) previous answer. I turned out to be caused by `state_is_tuple`.